# How can I sort a word table by specific string, which is a time like HH:MM inside each line of the first column

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with three tables inside it (like the one below), which I need to sort by the hour presented inside each line on the first column (the first time reference encountered). If I apply a blind sort, like:

`ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Sort ExcludeHeader:= true, SortOrder:=wdSortOrderAscending`

on a table which begins not by the time reference but with some words other them the time, this type of sorting will not work as I need. It will only take in consideration the first word found in each line.
Can anyone have some idea on how to solve this problem?
For the purpose of an example, consider a table like this:

Descrição

| HEADER1 | HEADER2 |
| --- | --- |
| Às 11.00 iniciou.se a do Gr.# da NNN. | F |
| Às 16.18 iniciou-se a do Gr.# da FFF. | G |
| Das 07.05 às 16.57 a Bateria de Condensadores # da CCC. | K |
| Das 07.22 às 16.24 a do disjuntor IBBP de 400 kV da KKK. | D |
| Das 08.10 às 16.58 a do disjuntor # do módulo ## do PPPPP. | Y |
| Das 08.27 às 17.34 a do disjuntor IBBP de 220 kV da LLLL. | S |
| Das 09.00 iniciou-se a do Gr.# da JJ. | H |
| Das 10.00 às 14.59 os Gr.#, Gr.# e Gr.# da VVV. | R |
| Das 10.04 às 19.16 a Reactância Shunt da GGGG. | H |
| Das 14.00 às 15.23 o Gr.# e das 14.00 às 16.11 o Gr.# da HHH. | U |
| Das 14.00 às 16.55 o Gr.# da MMM. | A |

So I don't know the word by which will each line begins, but I need to ignore them during the sort process. Can I do this with some vba for a word document (docm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, r As Long
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl
    .Columns.Add beforecolumn:=.Columns(1)
    For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
      .Cell(r, 1).Range.Text = .Cell(r, 2).Range.Words.First
      .Cell(r, 2).Range.Words.First.Text = vbNullString
    Next
    .Sort ExcludeHeader:=True, FieldNumber:="Column 2", _
      SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, _
      SortOrder:=wdSortOrderAscending
    For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
      .Cell(r, 1).Merge Mergeto:=.Cell(r, 2)
      .Cell(r, 1).Range.Paragraphs.First.Range.Characters.Last.Text = vbNullString
    Next
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```